# Inherit problems in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, syntax-error

UPDATE: Added `Default.aspx.cs if it helps`

I'm new in ASP.Net and I'm having trouble making a website. I'm having an error saying `Could not load type 'wsclient._Default'`. What is my error?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
     AutoEventWireup="true" 
     CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
     Inherits="wsclient._Default" %>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using localhost;

namespace wsclient
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                lblmessage.Text = "First Loading Time: " +
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            else
                lblmessage.Text = "PostBack at: " +
                DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        }
        protected void btnservice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            StockService proxy = new StockService();
            lblmessage.Text = String.Format("Current SATYAM Price:{0}",
            proxy.GetPrice("SATYAM").ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx**

[image]

Comment: Did you ever rename this page?

Comment: Show us the outline structure of your code behind file `Default.aspx.cs`.

Comment: @Johnny No I haven't renamed it.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel: Are you using Visual Studio?

Comment: @K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉ I removed teh `usings` since SO says too much code

Comment: Did you change the project type? From "Web Project" to "Web Site"?

Comment: @K̨̩̭͚̘̗̻̞͈͖̙͙e̗̦̼̳̣̦͜͡v̢̝̟̗̱̯͉ I don't even know how, if you're referring to the project folder, no I haven't

Comment: I really have no background at all in asp.net

Comment: Can you post your ASPX page as well?

Comment: @alstonp I'll put it in an image since SO will say too much code

Comment: Is localhost the name of one of your classes?

Comment: @NatsuDragneel: Since your page is named "Default", so Inherits="wsclient._Default" seems abnormal to me. You may need to recall what you have done to this page.

Comment: @NatsuDragneel check the designer file and find out the class name same as _Default in that namespace?

Comment: @Johnny renamed it to `Default` at first still getting the same error

Comment: @NatsuDragneel: Simply my experience. To make things easier, don't rename and don't copy/paste .aspx pages in Visual Studio. If you need to create a new page, just 'New' a page.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying your code like this:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="wsclient_Default" %>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class wsclient_Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            lblmessage.Text = "First Loading Time: " +
            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
        else
            lblmessage.Text = "PostBack at: " +
            DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    }
    protected void btnservice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StockService proxy = new StockService();
        lblmessage.Text = String.Format("Current SATYAM Price:{0}",
        proxy.GetPrice("SATYAM").ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. the only other thing I can think of is to get rid of your `<asp:Button ID="btnpostback" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server" Text="Post Back" />` code since you don't have a handler defined for "Button1_Click"

Answer (score 0):

Simply change "CodeBehind" to "CodeFile" in  your Defualt.aspx page "Line 1"

Comment: Other than you can check your VS version. Select the site on IIS, click ASP.NET tab, select ASP.NET version dropdown box and chceck its right or wrong.